# Full disk access for TeXShop on a Mac

Tags: texshop

On my Mac running OS Big Sur, I cannot save or compile TexShop files
unless I assign Full Disk Access to TeXShop in my system preferences;
is there a way around this?

Comment: I suspect that TeXShop may need Full Disk Access to access the TeX Distribution which is in /use/local.

Comment: I can run TeXShop on Big Sur with no problem.

Comment: @egreg : is Full Disk Access set for TeXShop on your system? It is on my system.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I clicked nowhere and set nothing about “full disk access”.

Comment: @egreg : Look under the Privacy tab of the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I see nothing about TeXShop.